# Solving a equation by giving conditions

Tags: equation-solving

In the model B=0 and N=0 are trivial solutions. So,I want to know if there are other solutions except these. I want to solve the following

```
Eu = gamma*Et/(a2*b + gamma)
N = 1/(2*(k3 - k5*Eu))*((a1*b*Eu - b*k4 + k6 - k7*Eu) + 
    Sqrt[(-a1*b*Eu + b*k4 - k6 + k7*Eu)^2 - 
      4*(k3 - k5*Eu)*(-b*k8 + k9*b*Eu)])

Be = -b + k - (a1*k*Eu/r1) - d1*k*N/(r1*(c*N + b)) - d4*k/r1
totalB = (r1 - a1*Eu - (d1*N/(c*N + b)) - d4)*k/r1

Solve[r2*Be*(1 - (totalB/k)) + a1*b*Eu - d2*Be*N/(cN + Be) == 0, b]
```

But, Mathematica takes a long time to solve this and I am not sure if it is because when B=0 and N=0, then it faces the situation 0/0. So, is there a way to tell Mathematica, to ignore (0,0) solution and look for other solutions?

Comment: Not good idea to assign to `N` as a variable. Are you sure there was no beep when you did that? on version 11.2 I get a loud beep with error `Set::wrsym: Symbol N is Protected.`

Comment: I also noticed you wrote `c*N` in one place and `cN` in another. Space in important in Mathematica. `cN` is not the same as `c N`.

Comment: In addition to the two issues Nasser mentioned, you have 19 unknowns, and b is nestled inside square roots. This isn't going to be easy to find the solutions for.

Comment: Also when $N$ and $b$ are both zero, the equation is not zero.

Comment: @Nasser I am new to Mathematica. So I want to know why it isn't good to assign `N` as a variable? Shouldn't cpaital letters be used as variables? Also with space does `c N` imply `C*N`?

Comment: @KraZug By system what I meant was I have a system of ODEs and I am trying to find the steady states. So I am setting each ODE to 0. In the system of ODE I know 0,0 is a steady state. But I want to know if there are other steady states. If I can solve `Solve[r2*Be*(1 - (totalB/k)) + a1*b*Eu - d2*Be*N/(cN + Be) == 0, b]`, which I only have in terms of `B`, I can find the steady states. The issue is I am finding it hard to find these steady states by hand and so decided to use Mathematica.

Comment: `N` is a function, which gives the numerical value of its argument. Similarly `D` is used for differentiation, `E` is the Exponential function. Basically don't use single capital letters as variables.

Comment: Putting a space does imply multiplication, but in your last line you don't have a space between `c` and `N`. Taking your last line and using `/.{b->0,n->0}`, the expression is not zero. You should probably put your equations up then